# Generate Token method - code parameter UPS API

Tags: ups

Where can I find the code parameter used in the Generate Token method?

The description of the parameter is: "Authorization code from the UPS login system."

In [this link](https://developer.ups.com/api/reference?loc=en_US#operation/GenerateToken) you can find the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you truly need this API?   It's only used if you're getting a token for *another* user.  If it's for *your* account (e.g. to get rates), you should use the `CreateToken` API, which does not have that parameter.

https://developer.ups.com/api/reference?loc=en_US#operation/CreateToken

Comment: Right, I was wrong. Finally I used CreateToken API and it is good for me.

Comment: Great! Please mark this answer as correct so people know your problem has been solved.

Comment: I'm new here and I don't have 15 reputation to cast a vote